# data download with set user-agent c++

Tags: c++, http

I have a function to upload information to a byte array, but it ends with - `if (!Httpsendrequest(httprequest, szHeaders, strlen(szhheaders), szRequest, strlen(szRequest)))`

```
string GetUrlData(const string& url, LPCSTR host, string& output)
{
    string request_data = "";
    output = "";
    HINTERNET hIntSession = InternetOpenA("token", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
   if (!hIntSession)
   {
       return request_data;
   }
    HINTERNET hHttpSession = InternetConnectA(hIntSession, host, 80, 0, 0, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL);
   if (!hHttpSession)
   {
       return request_data;
   }
    HINTERNET hHttpRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hHttpSession, "GET", url.c_str()
        , 0, 0, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
   if (!hHttpSession)
   {
       return request_data;
   }
   char* szHeaders = ("Content-Type: text/html\r\nUser-Agent: License");
   char szRequest[1024] = { 0 };
   if (!HttpSendRequestA(hHttpRequest, szHeaders, strlen(szHeaders), szRequest, strlen(szRequest)))
{
       qDebug()<<"BLYA";
       return request_data;
   }
    CHAR szBuffer[1024] = { 0 };
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
   while (InternetReadFile(hHttpRequest, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer) - 1, &dwRead) && dwRead)
   {
        request_data.append(szBuffer, dwRead);
   }
    InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
    InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
    output = request_data;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to add the C tag again, which I removed, but please give a reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "it ends"?

Comment: this HttpSendRequestAfunction returns false

Comment: @ДмитрийМинин and what does `GetLastError()` tell you when `HttpSendRequestA()` fails? From the docmentation: "*Returns TRUE if successful, or FALSE otherwise. **To get extended error information, call GetLastError**.*"

Answer (score 0):

The failure might have something to do with the fact that `szHeaders` is missing `\r\n` on the `User-Agent` header.  Every header you send ust be terminated with `\r\n`.  And BTW, there is no reason to send a `Content-Type` header in a `GET` request, since there is no message body being sent to the server.

Also, your code has a bunch of memory leaks if anything goes wrong. You need to close every handle you successfully open.

Also, there is no point in having both a return value and an output parameter that return the same data.  Pick one or the other.  I would suggest using a `bool` return value and a `string` output parameter.

Try something more like this:

```
bool GetUrlData(const string& resource, const string& host)
{
    output.clear();
    bool result = false;

    HINTERNET hIntSession = InternetOpenA("token", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (!hIntSession) {
        qDebug() << "InternetOpen failed, error: " << GetLastError();
        return false;
    }

    HINTERNET hHttpSession = InternetConnectA(hIntSession, host.c_str(), 80, 0, 0, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL);
    if (!hHttpSession) {
        qDebug() << "InternetConnect failed, error: " << GetLastError();
        InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
        return false;
    }

    HINTERNET hHttpRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hHttpSession, "GET", resource.c_str(), 0, 0, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
    if (!hHttpRequest) {
        qDebug() << "HttpOpenRequest failed, error: " << GetLastError();
        InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
        InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
        return false;
    }

    const char* szHeaders = "User-Agent: License\r\n";
    if (!HttpSendRequestA(hHttpRequest, szHeaders, -1, NULL, 0)) {
        qDebug() << "HttpSendRequest failed, error: " << GetLastError();
        InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
        InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
        InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
        return false;
    }

    char szBuffer[1024];
    DWORD dwRead = 0;

    do {
        if (!InternetReadFile(hHttpRequest, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), &dwRead)) {
            qDebug() << "InternetReadFile failed, error: " << GetLastError();
            InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
            InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
            InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
            return false;
        }

        if (dwRead == 0)
            break;

        output.append(szBuffer, dwRead);
    }
    while (true);

    return true;
}
```